# Existing Drag-and-Drop Application/Framework in Javascript

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, javascript-framework

Does anyone here know of a Javascript application (something similar to Lightbox, only not for images) for drag-and-drop, preferably running on the Prototype Javascript Framework?

Alternatively, I'm open to using jQuery or something else that's supported by the major browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.7.2/Draggable since you are open to jQuery.
The prototype alternative using the scriptcaulous library: http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/draggable

regards

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery and jQuery-UI, you will be able to use drag-drop features.

http://jqueryui.com/